# Efficient way to add/remove objects [ multiple attributes]

Tags: java, performance, list

I'm finding a efficient way to add a object with some rules to a List.
For example, I have this object

```
Car [int year, String brand, int cost]
```

Imaging that I have a List with this values:

```
[2011, "Renault", 100]
[2011, "Mazda", 120]
[2011, "Ferrari", 150]    

[2011, "Mazda", 100]
[2011, "Ferrari", 130]
[2011, "Renault", 200]
```

Rules:

1. If I want one Car[**2011, Mazda**, 150] I will replace the [**2011, Mazda,** 120], to update the cost.
2. If I want add a car with Car[**2011**, Renault, **120**] I want to replace the [**2011**, "Mazda", **120**].
3. If don't have match with the brand, I want to add for year and cost.

So, I want an efficient way that doing match with some attributes, and add object with this rules.

Someone, has any idea?

Comment: show us what code you have written ? and where are you stuck with ?

Comment: I have one way to do this, but I'm using a for and a lot of if/else statement. I'm looking for a best way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to achieve trivially. You can keep a couple of maps with keys `[year, cost]` and `[year, model]`. Give list index of corresponding object as value of map.

Every time you add an object, you pick two attributes, make key from those, and check if it exists in map. If it does, replace the corresponding object, if not add an entry.

While brute force approach will requires `O(n)` reads and one write to add new entry, this approach brings it down to two reads and two writes in case of a hit and two reads and three writes in case of a miss.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to store the key value pairs. Key can be combination of year + model, and value can be just the cost or the entire Car object.

Comment: I hope you meant map and not set?

Answer (score 0):

Hum, if I understood you correctly, you want to dive into `List`s. They are pretty straight forward:

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
Car mazda = new Car(2011, "Mazda", 150);
carList.add(mazda);
```

To remove a car:

```
Car mazda = new Car(2011, "Mazda", 150);
carList.add(mazda);
carList.remove(mazda); // no more mazda...
```

More about lists from [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: this is just to add and remove a element of the list :/